# How do you make the caption in a Figure fill horizontally?

Tags: horizontal

I have a tex for rendering a figure below, in which the figure caption has text which is **not** filling the page horizontally.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{image} \\
\flushleft \noindent {\bf Figure 1}: ver very veryverylongword short word short word ververyveryverylongword ververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongwordwordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short word
\end{figure}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

**My Question:** how do I get the text to fill the space horizontally? I do not like how on the right side, the text does not fill all the way to the side. (best would be that the very last line does not fill, but all other preceding lines do horizontally fill)

I am purposefully avoiding using \caption{} to caption this figure (the reason for this is that I do not want my Figure to be numbered in my table of contents, and this was the only way I could make it work for some reason)

Comment: `\flushleft` (which should never be used as a command it is the implementation of `\begin{flushleft}` should be written `\raggedright` and the only effect it has is to remove justification, so if you want justified paragraphs remove that.  Also note that `\bf`  may be defined in your document class for legacy compatibility but it has not been defined in latex by default since 1993. also use grouping to make centering just apply to the image not the following text (eg use `\begin{center}..\end{center}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem right. Why you not use `\caption` directive to writing caption? Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{example-image-duck} \\
\caption{Very very veryverylongword short word short word ververyveryverylongword ververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongwordwordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short wordververyveryverylongword short word short word}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?